# Create a union type based on a nested property

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have the following types:

```
interface FooAction {
    type: "foo";
    data: any;
}

interface BarAction {
    type: "bar";
    data: any;
}

type AllActions = FooAction | BarAction;
```

Given `AllActions`, how do I generate a union type based on the `type` property? I would like to retrieve a type:

`type AllTypes = "foo" | "bar"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an [index type query](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types):

```
type AllTypes = AllActions['type'] // same as "foo" | "bar"
```

Answer (score 3):

You were close! Since they both have the `type` property you can add `["type"]` to your union to grab only the types of the `type` properties.

```js
interface FooAction {
    type: "foo";
    data: any;
}

interface BarAction {
    type: "bar";
    data: any;
}

type AllActions = (FooAction | BarAction)["type"]; // "foo" | "bar"
```

[TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt0EEFmOkZAbwChlkwBPABwgC5kAiGTRgbjOQBM4w4G4IShwC+JEqEixEKAEJwoOPAWKcqtBowBGC9px58BQ0ePUosAGwtL8IAM7IAvMgAUGbLlvIAPsnmLPAgBKAG1GM0YAXTZkAHpYphZ0Rh8mHShGEiA)